# Connecting Apache Superset to hive database

Tags: python, hive, apache-superset

I am trying to connect hive database from apache superset but getting error, how to resolve that, Please help me out.

My URL- hive://hive@myhost:10000/mydatabase

but getting this error-
ERROR: Please check your connection details and database settings, and ensure that your database is accepting connections, then try connecting again.

Comment: Question needs more detail on your specific setup and the commands you are trying to run.

Comment: My hive is installed in ubuntu and I am trying to make connection with superset using this URL in apache superset UI, both are in same server URL- hive://hive@{ipaddress}:10000/{mydatabase} -@Vincent Rupp